# Send React component's HTML to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a react component, `<ReviewScreen />`. It takes in some props, styles them, and presents them. I need to convert this component into HTML, and send it to my backend so that I can generate a PDF on my server.

I tried:

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import ReviewScreen from '../somePath';

const html = renderToStaticMarkup(ReviewScreen)
// ... send the html variable to backend using some HTTP library
```

Problem: the `html` variable is always empty. My question is: a) is this a 'good' way of doing what I'm trying to achieve? b) is there a better method?

UPDATE: Changing to `<ReviewScreen />` actually gets a response. However, I forgot to mention that this component also talks to my Redux store which results in an **Invariant Violation: Could not find “store”** error.

Comment: The function expects a React element, not a class: `const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<ReviewScreen />)` (note that your question title is misleading, your actual issue is that `renderToStaticMarkup()` returns an empty string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderToStaticMarkup` takes in an element, not the component type - you'd need to do this:

```
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<ReviewScreen />)
```

Or, without JSX:

```
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(ReviewScreen))
```

That said, I think you would be better off generating the HTML on the server instead - rendering arbitary markup sent from the client seems like it could get messy.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I could preserve my client side styling on the server in that way though? That's my only issue with that.

Comment: Hm, hard to say without seeing what exactly your styling is doing - I think it'd be worth asking that as a seperate question :)

Comment: @MertMumtaz If you're asking how to render a PDF on the server that uses styling like the browser does, that's going to be pretty much impossible. TBH I'd rethink this entire approach and just create a PDF on the server, without React. Anything like borders, shadows, gradients etc. has to implemented using PNGs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<ReviewScreen />)
```

Not:

```
const html = renderToStaticMarkup(ReviewScreen)
```